# Abstract Algebra: Quotient ring, ideal, and isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, ring-isomorphism

I need help with the following exam exercise, my teacher didn’t post the answer and I can’t manage to solve it.

In $ A=\mathbb{Z}[i]=\{a+bi \ : \ a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\} $ we consider $a=7+56i; \ b=3+3i; \ c=1+8i$. We will write $(a)$ to refer to the ideal generated by $a$

1.- Prove that $\frac{A}{(a)}$ isn’t a field. Where  $\frac{A}{(a)}$ is the quotient ring of $A$ by the ideal generated by $a$.

However, prove there exists an isomorphism between $\frac{A}{(a)}$ and $A \times B \times C$ where $A,B,C$ are three fields.

2.- Find out whether the elements $\overline{b}:= b + (a), \ \overline{c} \in \frac{A}{(a)}$ are invertible elements in $\frac{A}{(a)}$ or not. If they are, calculate their inverses.

EDIT: With the help of the answers below I’ve managed to do the following.

1.- A is an Euclidean domain, so it is a PID. 
Let $N$ be the norm application, so $N(a)=3185=5\cdot 637 = (7+56i)(7-56i)$ therefore $a$ isn’t prime in $A$, as a result $(a)$ isn’t a prime ideal in $A$. This implies $(a)$ isn’t a maximal ideal in the set of principal ideals of $A$, but $A$ is a PDI so $(a)$ isn’t maximal in $A$ so  $\frac{A}{(a)}$  isn’t a field.

For the second part, we can use the Chinese Remainder Theorem, if we can express $(a)$ as the intersection of three coprime ideals (i.e I.J coprime ideals iff $I+J=A$) we can make use of it.

$a=7(1+8i)$ and $N(1+8i)=65=5 \cdot 13 = (2+i)(2-i)13$ and one can easily check that $(1+8i)/(2+i)=2+3i$. That gives us $a=7(2+i)(2+3i)$ where all of them are prime in $A$ therefore their ideals are prime too. (I haven’t managed to see if they are coprime)

We also know that $(n) \cap (m)=(lcm(m,n))$ and as  $a=7(2+i)(2+3i)$ we have $(a)=(7) \cap(2+i) \cap(2+3i)$ but all of them are prime, so that intersection equals the product of all of them.

Now by the Chinese Remainder Theorem we get that there exists an isomorphism

$$
f: \frac{A}{(a)} \longrightarrow \frac{A}{(7)} \times \frac{A}{(2+i)} \times \frac{A}{(2+3i)}
$$
where those quotient rings are fields since their ideals are prime which implies maximal.

2.- I’m still stuck on this one, but I’ve managed to do something:
To see if $\overline{b}$ is invertirle we have to find $\overline{t}$ such that $\overline{b} \overline{t}= \overline{1}$ which translates into $\overline{1-bt}=0 \Rightarrow 1-bt \in (a) \Rightarrow \lambda a =1-bt \Rightarrow 1=\lambda a +bt $ and this last expression I know it’s a Bézout Identity but I don’t know how to work with it in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $a=7+56i=7(1+8i)$. Note also that $|1+8i|^2=65=5\cdot13$. Try
$$
\frac{1+8i}{2+i}
$$
and you'll have a full factorization of $a$. The rest should follow easily.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I’ve edited the question to add what I’ve done.

Answer (score 1):

The quotient $\frac{A}{(a)}$ is a field if and only if the ideal $(a)$ is maximal. The ideal $(a)$ is maximal if and only if $a$ is irreducible. But $a=7(1+8i)$, so it is not irreducible, hence $\frac{A}{(a)}$ is not a field.

Well, you should be able to do the second part now by yourself. Let me know if you get in trouble.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! I’ve added my answer to the question and the doubts I still have about the exercise.